# Strongloop/Loopback 'slc build --npm' doesn't honor .npmignore

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, loopbackjs, strongloop

My app has a client and an API in the same repo. The API side is built with  `slc build --npm`, while the client is built with `npm run build` as triggered within the slc build command. I am trying to build the deployable .tgz file and *exclude* the `client/` and `build/` artifacts (among a bunch of other stuff that I don't necessarily want on my API servers).

Am I missing a configuration setting?

My .npmignore clearly has entries for

```
client/
devops/
dist/
```

yet after building if I untar the archive, everything listed in `.npmignore` is still included. Is this just not supported?

I guess `slc build --npm` is not running the actual `npm pack` command internally and just doing a custom thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that it is *not* running `npm pack`. It is actually using a module that was explicitly created to ignore the `.npmignore` file in your module as well as any dependencies.

The reason this was done is because many modules with binary add-ons are configured to not publish their compiled parts, and this makes it impossible to bundle those packages with their binaries pre-compiled so that they can be deployed to an environment that doesn't have a compiler.

It sounds like the behavior could use some refinement, like only ignoring the dependencies ignore files.

Comment: Thanks. So if it *did* honor .npmignore straight up, the .tgz package would scrub all of the downstream dep modules that are compiled with `npm install --scripts`? Yeah that's no good. There def should be a `--ignore-depth` flag for this.

Comment: Just a quick followup on this - if I were to quickly add in some tgz manipulation on the resulting `slc build` tarball, would it work with a native `tar cvzf package/` or should I use `strong-pack` to re-tar the cleaned up package folder after I've deleted stuff?

Comment: It should work with either. The main advantage to strong-pack is that it is pure JS, so it works on platforms that don't support tgz out of the box (aka Windows).